# Implementing a Search Box using ASP.NET MVC, SQL Server, Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, search

I have no experience building a search solution, but I'd like to have a search box within my solution and I don't know where to even begin.  Are there cool SQL Server tricks that I can use to make my search solution performant (I'm using a hosted SQL 2008 server)  I'd love pointers to a multi-step tutorial that starts me off with a simple query search solution...and then layers on more advanced code and features.

Comment: controller -> stored proc -> SQL Server 2008 FTS catalogu

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually say whether you need/want a 'spider' to index your site "as is" (like Google; which is useful if your searchable content on each page comes from many different tables/objects/entities) or whether you just want to query EF using full-text-search-like syntax to return a collection of Entities?

If you are interesting in the 'spider' approach - here's a CodeProject article for a small ASP.NET Search Engine "[Searcharoo](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/Searcharoo_7.aspx)". It is a web-crawling search engine for small-ish sites (it doesn't use a database at all), so it may not be applicable for your situation.
The code is also at [searcharoo.codeplex.com](http://searcharoo.codeplex.com/) and there are 7 articles on how it works/was built at [Searcharoo.net](http://searcharoo.net) (disclaimer: I wrote them; I hope they are interesting/useful).

If you need to search your database directly, you should probably look into SQL Server 2008's Full Text Search feature (assuming `LIKE` isn't sophisticated enough for your needs). We used info from [this article (free registration)](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Full-Text+Search+(2008)/64248/) to set-up SQL Full Text Search on a work project... no EF in our solution though.

Also, as you might know StackOverflow is built with ASP.NET MVC - they blogged about some [problems with SQL 2008 FTS](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/sql-2008-full-text-search-problems/). There's also [some info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499247/sql-server-2008-full-text-search-fts-versus-lucene-net) on SQL FTS versus Lucene.NET (which is another search engine you could research) that might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Read this article:

- [Create a Site Search Engine in ASP.NET](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4389/create-a-site-search-engine-in-aspnet/)

If you don't have to program an engine yourself you could consider using [Google Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/coop/cse/). There are couple of articles about this:

- [Using Google Co-op's Custom Search
  Engine](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CustomSearchEngine.aspx)
- [Implementing Search in ASP.NET with Google Custom Search](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Implementing-Search-in-ASP-NET-with-Google-Custom-Search.aspx)

Also could be useful:

- [Helping Visitors Search Your Site By Creating an OpenSearch Provider](https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043830/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073008-1.aspx)